# Which characters have a shield-breaking attack/combo?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I was reading [this article](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Shield#Shield_breaking) of the official SSB wiki about shield breaking:

> Certain moves, like Marth's fully charged Shield Breaker, can break shields in one hit.

Which other character(s) can do this?

Comment: being essentially a clone character, Lucina also has a shield breaker neutral special.

Comment: Bowser's down-B can do it.

Comment: Jigglypuff side-B. And Peach down-B can pull out a Mr.Saturn which is also a shield breaker. A well landed yoshi's d-air can put enough shield presure to break it.

Comment: Pretty much every character has a move that can break shields.  The real question is "which characters cannot break shields with a single move of their own"